# Why prebuilt of protocol buffer doesn't contain any header files

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using protocol buffer first time. I am able to make and compile .proto

file from protoc (protoc-3.9.1-win64). But problem is that when i want to use

compiled files i am getting error google/protobuf/*.h not found even i have

setup include path to ./protoc-3.9.1-win64/include.

include folder of protoc's contain only contain .proto files

there are no header files in it ?

[image]

do i need to build from source ?

Comment: Which header files are not found?

Comment: google/protobuf/*h i.e. #include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>

Comment: copy headers from source code and try, https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v3.9.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded the package for the `protoc` compiler.

However, the C++ library is in separate package, `protobuf-cpp-3.9.1.zip`, where `cpp` stands for `C++`. There are multiple packages available for other languages, too.

Comment: do i need to build it with cmake?

Comment: @Mohit Generally yeah, though I guess you could grab the binary libraries from the `protoc` package, and the headers from `cpp` package. But because C++ is not fully binary compatible between different compilers, it is better to build it yourself.